# openCV Kalman filter with java - basic concept

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision, kalman-filter

what I'm doing is programming a visual odometry algorithm, so an algorithm that calculates the current position and pose of a mobile (android → Java) device based on image features.

The result, I currently receive from the algortihm contains numerous outliers, that lead to high drift and wrong trajectories.

The algorithm basically takes two frames and calculates the camera rotation and translation between them. Then, through adding these values up, the total position and rotation as seen from the starting point/pose are calculated by this:

```
   totalRotation = multiply(rotation,totalRotation);
   Core.add(position,(multiply(totalRotation,translation)), position);
```

Where `totalRotation` is the absolute rotation to the starting point, `position` is the position in space (stating point is 0,0,0), `rotation` is the rotation between the last and the current frame, `translation` is the translation between the last and the current frame and `multiply` is my own method, that just computes the matrix product.

So I have a total of 12 values here:

- The relative motion between the last and current frame: x,y,z,alpha,beta,gamma
- And the position/pose in space relative to the starting point: x',y',z',alpha', beta', gamma'

I want to smooth my trajectory (and improve my "current position" values) with an openCV Kalman filter.

Can anyone tell me how I need to set up my filter? I'm very new to the Kalman filters and I'm having trouble understanding what the individual parameters mean and how/when to use which method.of it.

Thanks in advance!